# Is the Phone field type ever searchable?

Tags: apex, search, global-search, content-search

Is the Phone field type ever searchable? Have platform dev questions about searchable fields but have come across conflicting answers.

Basically I just want to understand is Phone field type searchable using global search? Also for number field.

Are there any other searching methods that limit field types that are searchable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I just want to understand is Phone field type searchable using global search? Also for number field.
>
> Are there any other searching methods that limit field types that are searchable?

The table on the help article - [**Searchable Fields by Object in Lightning Experience**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5), lists down which fields on which objects are searchable. As for the *Phone* and *Number* fields (on standard objects), those are listed in the table and thus are searchable.

Also refer to the below excerpts which provides details as what's available and what not based on FLS or their availability.

> Not all object and fields are searchable, so reference the table to determine which records you can find with Salesforce search.
>
> When you search for a value in a field that's hidden from you by field-level security, your results include the record that contains the field. However, you can't see the field.

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to what fields are searchable for objects. You might want to check out the following resources:

- [Searchable Objects and Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields.htm&type=5)
- [Searchable Fields by Object in Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_cex.htm&type=5)
- [Searchable Fields by Object in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5)

> Your search results for a particular object depend on two factors: the
>   type of search and the searchable fields for that object.

Also, an important note:

> When you search for a value in a field that's hidden from you by field-level security, your results include the record that contains the field. However, you can't see the field.